# Get the ID of a dynamic text field via dynamically created button

Tags: javascript, jquery

See below code. I'm creating two text fields dynamically. In one of those text fields 2 buttons are also created. When either of these buttons are clicked how could I get the ID of the text field that doesn't have buttons?

```
<button type="button" id="tfButton">Add text</button>
<div id="InputsWrapper"></div>
<div id="OuterWrapper"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var tfCont = 0;
    var InputsWrapper = $("#InputsWrapper");
    var x = InputsWrapper.length; 
    var namefield = $("#tfButton");

    $(namefield).click(function() {
        tfCont++;

        $(InputsWrapper).append('<div>' + '<div class="name" id="InputsWrapper_0' + tfCont + '">' + '<input type="textarea" id="field_' + tfCont + '" class="fTypex" placeholder="Thought of the day..." data-tfcount="' + tfCont + '"/><button type="button" runclass0">Run</button><button type="button" class="removeclass0">Next</button>' + '<br>' + '</div>' + '</div>');

         $("#OuterWrapper").append('<div id="textLayer_' + tfCont + '">' + '<input type="textarea" id="tf_' + tfCont + '" data-tfcount="' + tfCont + '">' + '</div>');

        x++;
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on("click blur keyup", "input.fTypex", function() {
        var tfc = $(this).data("tfcount");
        $("#tf_" + tfc).val(this.value);
    });
});
```

Comment: do you mean get the id of the input in `OuterWrapper`?

Comment: also, way to many id's, your system seems a bit flawed, do you mean to keep adding inputs to just the same 2 fields?

Comment: @SpYk3HH: Yes, the ID of the input and the DIV in `OuterWrapper`

Comment: updated my answer, hope that helps you some

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

I know I didn't make use of your data attributes. However, there are million ways to re-include them, I simply thought it was best to show you an easier way without relying on multiple similar ID's, found by using data. That way just seemed like more work and headache, to me anyway.

## jsFiddle: live example

```
$(function() {
    function createFields(e) {
        var inWrap = $('<div />', { class: 'name-wrapper' }),
            nameWrap = $('<div />', { class: 'name' }).appendTo(inWrap),
            outWrap = $('<div />');

        nameWrap.append(
            $('<input />', { class: 'fTypex', placeholder: 'Thought of the day...', type: 'textarea' }),
            $('<button />', { text: 'Run', type: 'button' }),
            $('<button />', { text: 'Next', type: 'button' })
        );

        outWrap.append(
            $('<input />', { type: 'textarea' })
        );

        $('#InputsWrapper').append(inWrap);
        $('#OuterWrapper').append(outWrap);
    }

    $(document)
        .on('click', '#tfButton', createFields)
        .on('click', '#InputsWrapper button', function(e) {
            var i = $(this).closest('.name-wrapper').index(),
                inp = $('#OuterWrapper input')[i],
                $inp = $(inp);

            console.log(i, inp, $inp);

            //  could use like
            $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
            $inp.addClass('highlight');
        })
})
```

---

And if you insist on your data attributes and that weird `runclass0` attr and the other class, here's an alternate fiddle including those little items. You'll notice very little change in structure tho.

#### Alt jsFiddle

```
$(function() {
    function createFields(e) {
        var inWrap = $('<div />', { class: 'name-wrapper' }),
            nameWrap = $('<div />', { class: 'name' }).appendTo(inWrap),
            outWrap = $('<div />'),
            iCnt = $('#InputsWrapper .name-wrapper').length + 1;

        nameWrap.append(
            $('<input />', { class: 'fTypex', 'data-tfcount': iCnt, id: 'field_'+iCnt, placeholder: 'Thought of the day...', type: 'textarea' }),
            '<button runclass0 type="button">Run',
            $('<button />', { class: 'removeclass0', text: 'Next', type: 'button' })
        );

        outWrap.append(
            $('<input />', { 'data-tfcount': iCnt, id: 'tf_'+iCnt, type: 'textarea' })
        );

        $('#InputsWrapper').append(inWrap);
        $('#OuterWrapper').append(outWrap);
    }
    $(document)
        .on('click', '#tfButton', createFields)
        .on('click', '#InputsWrapper button', function(e) {
            var i = $(this).closest('.name-wrapper').index(),
                inp = $('#OuterWrapper input')[i],
                $inp = $(inp);

            //  see console for more info: F12 in most of today's browsers
            if (console['log']) console.log(i, inp, $inp);

            //  could use like
            $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
            $inp.addClass('highlight');
        })
})
```